# Should I give staffing agency my signed offer letter?

Tags: recruitment, hiring-process

I was recently directly hired by a company, but was introduced to them through a staffing agency. Several days later after filling out paperwork for the company (and being given a final good luck by the staffing agency), my "recruiter" is asking for the signed offer letter. I don't think I have the signed letter because it was digitally signed on a website, but I have the details of the offer. Are there any pros/cons of finding and sending the offer letter to the staffing agency. Aren't my obligations to the staffing agency completely/shouldn't they be reaching out the company and not me?

Edit: I decided to just give them the offer letter, but now they want me to apply again on the staffing agency website for their own purposes.

Comment: Yeah, so you shouldn't be talking with the staffing agency. Assuming they were engaged by your employer, you relationship with them has ended. Do not leak potentially private information to them.

Answer (score 4):

That depends somewhat on who engaged the staffing agency: you or your employer. If they act on behalf of your employer, you should NOT give them anything and let your employer handle them in whatever way they feel is best.

If you did engage them, you should carefully look at the terms and conditions that you agreed to and when you engaged them. If this require you to disclose details of the offer you should clear it with your employer first.

Comment: Exactly right. The person that engaged with them is responsible for sharing that information.

Answer (score 1):

The staffing agency wants the offer letter so they can substantiate their 10% commission.  This is normal practice, and it's just to make sure that the company you've been placed at is being honest with the final amount you were offered for your salary.

The agency has provided a valuable service to both you and the company.  Help 'em out.

Answer (score -2):

Why wouldn't you do your best to fulfill this request? They helped you get the job. I can't think of any reason not to do it, and I see little point in antagonizing a valuable professional contact.

Even if you signed it digitally, it's usually possible to print it to a PDF or, that failing, take a screenshot.

Comment: I suspect that the agency don't trust the salary that the company are reporting to them, which is used to calculate the commission to be paid to the agency.